# How do I locate string and integer data in python

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

I would like to locate this data from a page source

```
"location": {"latitude": 35.4677026, "longitude": -80.6093396}
```

currently I am running this code

```
floats = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d+\.\d+", str(soup))
  for i in range(len(floats)):
      if len(floats[i]) > 9:
        LatLong.append(floats[i])
```

The output has the data I am looking for, but it also has data I don't want with it mixed in

Comment: Use python's json module instead of writing, complex, unmaintainable and buggy code…

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'll look into how to use json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

string_data = '{"location": {"latitude": 35.4677026, "longitude": -80.6093396}}'

data = json.loads(string_data)

if 'location' in data:
    # do something with the data
    print(data['location']['latitude'])
    print(data['location']['longitude'])
```

You should verify if the used keys exist in the data dictionary for avoid dictionary keys errors